# Only show value of Max rows with partition by?

Tags: sql-server, null, max, row, partition-by

the title might be a bit off however i'm trying to remove the values of a row without removing the actual row.

**This is my table:**

```
SELECT ID,CustomerID,Weight FROM Orders
```

[image]

What am i trying to accomplish is this:

[image]

The `MAX()` value of **ID** `Group By` **CustomerID** that would give me null values in `Weight` where max and group by is not set

Is it possible to do this in one line? with a `partiton by`?

Something like:

`SELECT MAX(ID)  over (partition by CustomerID,Weight)....` I know this is wrong but if possible to do without a join or CTE and only in one line in the select statement that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    CustomerID,
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY ID DESC) = 1 THEN [Weight]
        ELSE Null
    END AS [Weight]
FROM #Orders
ORDER BY ID
```

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Orders (
    ID int,
    CustomerID int,
    [Weight] int
)
INSERT INTO #Orders
    (ID, CustomerID, [Weight])
VALUES
    (1, 11, 100),
    (2, 11, 17),
    (3, 11, 35),
    (4, 22, 26),
    (5, 22, 78),
    (6, 22, 10030)
```

Output:

```
ID  CustomerID  Weight
1   11          NULL
2   11          NULL
3   11          35
4   22          NULL
5   22          NULL
6   22          10030
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        MAX_ID = MAX(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId),
        ID,
        CustomerId,
        Weight
        FROM Orders
)
SELECT
    ID,
    CustomerId,
    Weight = CASE WHEN ID = MAX_ID THEN Weight ELSE NULL END
    FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT ID,CustomerId,CASE WHEN ID= MAX(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId) THEN Weight ELSE NULL END AS Weight FROM Orders
```